# URL normalisation by Firebase hosting causing issues with Angular multiple auxiliary routes

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm investigating an unwanted side effect of Firebase Hosting. It tries normalising URLs with multiple slashes to a single slash by redirecting with a 301 the 'clean' URL.

For example, this happens (double slash between foo and bar):

`https://hostname/foo//bar` => HTTP 301 to: `https://hostname/foo/bar`

which does make sense!

But.. when using Angular and have multiple auxiliary routes those are seperated with 2 slashes as well by the Angular router, and those URLS will get redirected by Firebase hosting as well. For example:

`https://hostname/(outlet1:foo//outlet2:bar)` => HTTP 301 to: `https://hostname/%28outlet1:foo/outlet2:bar%29`

And thus removing the / between the two auxiliary routes (and encoding the ( and ) characters, but that's less relevant for this)

I cannot find any way of configuring this behaviour in Firebase, neither via console nor via `firebase.json`. Does anyone have any suggestion if this behaviour can be configured / disabled?

[edit]
This behaviour of the Angular Router is 'hardcoded'.

File: packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L335

```js
function serializeSegment(...)
  ...
  return `${serializePaths(segment)}/(${children.join('//')})`;
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L335